# UITableview section editable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

there are 5 section in my tableview 1)1 and 2 are not editable while 3,4,and 5 are editable
in section 1 am using checkbox,2 radio box , 3 insert cell , 4 delete cell ,5 move cell

so for last 3 i want my tableview will be come editable and sign of + and - will be shown in starting of cell.

and not for forst 2 section.
i tried - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

but this is not working. any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`.  You'll also want to implement [tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aeditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath%3a).

Also, are you calling [setEditing:animated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/setEditing%3aanimated%3a) on your UITableView to put the table into editing mode?  I assume you are, but it never hurts to double-check.

Comment: it is for whole tableview not for a particular section

Comment: @PJR - Call it from your `UIViewController`, when you want the table to go into editing mode.  If you just want to test it out, then call it from your `viewDidLoad` method.  And yes, it is for the whole tableview.  That is why you implement `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` to return `NO` for any sections you do not want to be editable.

Answer (score 5):

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

  NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
  if (section ==0)
    return NO;
  if (section ==1)
    return NO;
  if (section ==2)
    return YES;
  if (section ==3)
    return YES;
  if (section ==4)
    return YES;


 }



- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: ya but i have to specify setEdting: method?

Comment: It is not needed to check if things are working. But I have pasted the code for it anyway.

Comment: it is showing all section not editable and if i write   [myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
  [myTableView reloadData]; in viewdidload then it shows all editable and in the later case i m not getting didSelectRowAtIndexPath method called